# Is it the OS or individual applications that interpret keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm unfamiliar with how this all works, but here's my guess:

When you strike some keys on your keyboard, the signals go through the USB wire, and is interpreted by a keyboard driver on your the OS (since the OS recognizes that the device connected on that USB port is a keyboard). The OS then "publishes" the keys being struck (is this *stdin*?) to whatever application that is currently active (e.g. Chrome, Word, Notepad). If the application is in a state where it is accepting input, then it interprets the keys in whatever way it deems fit. Otherwise the "published" keys are simply ignored.

But I think that before passing off to the active application, the OS checks to see if what you typed was a Windows-wide keyboard shortcut (like Windows + D). However, some conventional shortcuts, like Ctrl+C, can be overridden by the application, even though most applications attempt to conform to convention and interpret Ctrl+C as as an attempt to copy something to the clipboard.

How accurate is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Keyboard Input Model**

The system provides device-independent keyboard support for applications by installing a keyboard device driver appropriate for the current keyboard. The system provides language-independent keyboard support by using the language-specific keyboard layout currently selected by the user or the application. The keyboard device driver receives scan codes from the keyboard, which are sent to the keyboard layout where they are translated into messages and posted to the appropriate windows in your application.
Assigned to each key on a keyboard is a unique value called a scan code, a device-dependent identifier for the key on the keyboard. A keyboard generates two scan codes when the user types a key—one when the user presses the key and another when the user releases the key.
The keyboard device driver interprets a scan code and translates (maps) it to a virtual-key code, a device-independent value defined by the system that identifies the purpose of a key. After translating a scan code, the keyboard layout creates a message that includes the scan code, the virtual-key code, and other information about the keystroke, and then places the message in the system message queue. The system removes the message from the system message queue and posts it to the message queue of the appropriate thread. Eventually, the thread's message loop removes the message and passes it to the appropriate window procedure for processing.

**Keyboard Focus and Activation**

The system posts keyboard messages to the message queue of the foreground thread that created the window with the keyboard focus. The keyboard focus is a temporary property of a window. The system shares the keyboard among all windows on the display by shifting the keyboard focus, at the user's direction, from one window to another. The window that has the keyboard focus receives (from the message queue of the thread that created it) all keyboard messages until the focus changes to a different window.
A thread can call the GetFocus function to determine which of its windows (if any) currently has the keyboard focus. A thread can give the keyboard focus to one of its windows by calling the SetFocus function. When the keyboard focus changes from one window to another, the system sends a WM_KILLFOCUS message to the window that has lost the focus, and then sends a WM_SETFOCUS message to the window that has gained the focus.
The concept of keyboard focus is related to that of the active window. The active window is the top-level window the user is currently working with. The window with the keyboard focus is either the active window, or a child window of the active window. To help the user identify the active window, the system places it at the top of the Z order and highlights its title bar (if it has one) and border.
The user can activate a top-level window by clicking it, selecting it using the ALT+TAB or ALT+ESC key combination, or selecting it from the Task List. A thread can activate a top-level window by using the SetActiveWindow function. It can determine whether a top-level window it created is active by using the GetActiveWindow function.
When one window is deactivated and another activated, the system sends the WM_ACTIVATE message. The low-order word of the wParam parameter is zero if the window is being deactivated and nonzero if it is being activated. When the default window procedure receives the WM_ACTIVATE message, it sets the keyboard focus to the active window.
To block keyboard and mouse input events from reaching applications, use BlockInput. Note, the BlockInput function will not interfere with the asynchronous keyboard input-state table. This means that calling the SendInput function while input is blocked will change the asynchronous keyboard input-state table.

**Keystroke Messages**

Pressing a key causes a WM_KEYDOWN or WM_SYSKEYDOWN message to be placed in the thread message queue attached to the window that has the keyboard focus. Releasing a key causes a WM_KEYUP or WM_SYSKEYUP message to be placed in the queue.
Key-up and key-down messages typically occur in pairs, but if the user holds down a key long enough to start the keyboard's automatic repeat feature, the system generates a number of WM_KEYDOWN or WM_SYSKEYDOWN messages in a row. It then generates a single WM_KEYUP or WM_SYSKEYUP message when the user releases the key.

**System and Nonsystem Keystrokes**
The system makes a distinction between system keystrokes and nonsystem keystrokes. System keystrokes produce system keystroke messages, WM_SYSKEYDOWN and WM_SYSKEYUP. Nonsystem keystrokes produce nonsystem keystroke messages, WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP.
If your window procedure must process a system keystroke message, make sure that after processing the message the procedure passes it to the DefWindowProc function. Otherwise, all system operations involving the ALT key will be disabled whenever the window has the keyboard focus. That is, the user won't be able to access the window's menus or System menu, or use the ALT+ESC or ALT+TAB key combination to activate a different window.
System keystroke messages are primarily for use by the system rather than by an application. The system uses them to provide its built-in keyboard interface to menus and to allow the user to control which window is active. System keystroke messages are generated when the user types a key in combination with the ALT key, or when the user types and no window has the keyboard focus (for example, when the active application is minimized). In this case, the messages are posted to the message queue attached to the active window.
Nonsystem keystroke messages are for use by application windows; the DefWindowProc function does nothing with them. A window procedure can discard any nonsystem keystroke messages that it does not need.

**Virtual-Key Codes Described**
The wParam parameter of a keystroke message contains the virtual-key code of the key that was pressed or released. A window procedure processes or ignores a keystroke message, depending on the value of the virtual-key code.

A typical window procedure processes only a small subset of the keystroke messages that it receives and ignores the rest. For example, a window procedure might process only WM_KEYDOWN keystroke messages, and only those that contain virtual-key codes for the cursor movement keys, shift keys (also called control keys), and function keys. A typical window procedure does not process keystroke messages from character keys. Instead, it uses the TranslateMessage function to convert the message into character messages. For more information about TranslateMessage and character messages, see Character Messages.

For more information, see the full version here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx

---

To specifically answer your question, if an application wants to intercept a system keystroke then it must catch it in the system message queue which is not the way applications typically work. The system will automatically create a special queue for each application which is more efficient for application to use because that queue doesn't include the messages intended for other applications. The system queue has all messages for all applications which means that any application which is reading it must throw out a lot of unneeded messages.